# What is a Post on SE?

Tags: discussion, support, wording

As far as I understand, the term **Post** means either **Question** or **Answer** on Stack Exchange Network. Hence should we use the words **Question** and **Answer** directly in the user interface for situations when the more specific word can be used instead?

E.g. `Post closed → Question closed` in [revision histories](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/37466/revisions) because we can close only questions, not answers.

Comment: related: [Stack Exchange Glossary - Dictionary of Commonly-Used Terms](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/40353/165773)

Comment: Can you clarify where you see the user interface using 'post closed' instead of 'question'? A quick scan of some questions closed as duplicate/too broad or migrated and the close-vote dialogue shows that those already seem to mention question instead of post.

Comment: @Tinkeringbell in any post (sorry, question) closed as duplicate for example, [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/37466/revisions)

Comment: I'm not sure this is a big deal. You are indeed correct that changing it to "question" would teach the more observant of the new users that questions can be closed, but it doesn't necessarily disprove "answers can be closed". Plus, people are usually not 100% careful with their wording, so they won't imply too many things of an automated post banner.

Comment: @M.A.R.ಠ_ಠ one small fix is no a big deal, but a lot of small bug fixes is a big deal.

Answer (score 5):

What you're suggesting is already implemented for **reviewing**, i.e. for those review queues where it says *posts*, they can either be related to a *question* or an *answer* (eg: First posts and/or low quality posts). Moreover, late answers can only be about an *answer* (so that's already implemented also).

And for some of the links below a question, this is what is currently implemented:

- **share**, i.e. when you share a *question*, the related popup includes "*... question*". And when you share a *answer*, the related popup includes "*... answer*".
- **flag**, i.e. when you flag a *question*, the various flagging-options don't use *post*. Instead, where relevant, it always says *question*. Same is true for flagging an *answer*.
- **reopen** a question, the related popup mentions "*reopen this question* ... *new answers can be added ...*" (no mention about *post* either).
- **protect** a question, the related popup mentions "*disallow answers* ..." (no mention about *post* either).

And apart from your example in the question, these seem to be the cases that could be refined:

- **edit** a question, the related popup mentions "*revise and improve this post*". Same is true for flagging an *answer*.
- **delete** a question, the related popup mentions "*vote to delete this post*". Same is true for deleting an *answer*.
- **undelete** a question, the related popup mentions "*vote to undelete this post*". Same is true for undeleting an *answer*.

Comment: Deleting an answer also says "Vote to delete this post? (25 votes remaining)". The advantage of this wording is that it's clearer that delete votes are shared between questions and answers.

Comment: @Glorfindel merci for helping me complete my *homework* (I needed some time to find a relevant popup). And at the same time add the edit and undelete actions also.

Answer (score 2):

I think participants understand what is meant by word *post* in different contexts.

Comment: We also know that we should be polite with others, but CoC banner is always displayed near the new contributor posts and user card. So I think we can simplify some situations on site for better understanding that closing is for question, not for the post in general.

Comment: While true, "Question closed" is much better.